# Is it a performance problem for TCP connection when too many zero window update packets occur?

Tags: performance, sockets, tcp, kernel

We meet a performance problem (maybe not) recently. Our programs run in a cluster which has 8 nodes. Each one creates a TCP persistent connection to other ones including itself. The client continually sends data flow to server. The data rate for each connection is about 50Mbps. The client first push the data to a queue then another thread sends the data to server. If the data rate increases a bit, for example, it arrives 62Mbps or 75Mbps, the queue of the client becomes full and the client has to drop some packets. We watch by 'netstat', and find that the Send-Q of the client is full of packets but the Recv-Q of the server is empty, as below.
[image]
[image]

It seems that the server cannot receive data immediately. Then we capture the packets with Wireshark. We find that when the problem occurs, there are too many zero window update packet described the below picture. We can find that when the sender receives a TCP ZeroWindow packet, it cannot send data continually. After 250ms the sender send a TCP Keep-Alive packet which is actually a window update probe packet, the receiver replies to the sender with the TCP Window Update packet. And after a short period, this process repeats again and again. For the sender, because it waits 250ms to probe the receiver's window size, so it can only send 4 times in a second. So it accumulates too many packets.
The problem is we don't why the program has such an appearance. The network link speed is 1000Mbps and it seems normal. And the CPU usage and free memory account are at a normal level. We googled for help. Some said that maybe the quota of TCP is not enough. So we doubles the value of /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mem. It seems that the method doesn't work.
The main clues we considered are the switch bug or kernel bugs. But we don't know how to verify.
So is there anyone who met the similar question? And how can we do if we want the receiver updates its window more rapidly. Or this is just a normal phenomena? Asking for help online!

By the way, our programs run in Linux OS, the kernel version is 3.10.0. It is a embedded OS. And the mainboard is Hi3536 which uses ARM architecture.
[image]

Comment: The packet lengths don't line up with the advertised widow size, so I'm guessing that a window scale factor has been negotiated that wireshark didn't see.  I've had problems with older equipment clearing the window scale options resulting in each side having a different view of what the scale factor is and resulting in issues like this.  I would suggest turning off window scaling on all machines with `sudo sysctl -w "net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=0"` and getting another capture showing zero windows.  We will then know that all the window advertisements are unscaled.

Comment: Thans very much first. You said that 'I've had problems with older equipment clearing the window scale options resulting in each side having a different view of what the scale factor is and resulting in issues like this', did you mean that if the equipment cleared the windown scale factor, they would had met the problem. So you suggested us to turn off the window scaling. And you thought the problem will appear if we take such an action. Do I understand you right? Thank you again.

Comment: There is not enough information to diagnose the problem, but it is possible that disabling window scaling will solve the problem, and I have seen situations where it has done so.  But even if it does not solve the problem, at least it will be clear what the window size means in any network capture, since there will be no window scale negotiated.

Comment: That sounds feasible. It's so nice of you. We are going to disable the window scaling factor to see if it will solve   the problem or improve it. And I'll follow up the effect.

Comment: That sounds feasible. It's so nice of you. We are going to disable the window scaling factor to see if it will solve   the problem or improve it. And I'll follow up the effect.

Comment: So what was the result?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. We set net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling to zero.It shows that the scale factor doesn't work. But the probelem still exists. Anyway I appreciate you very much!

Comment: If you can update the capture, it might be easier to diagnose what is going on now that window scaling if off (note that the setting doesn't survive a reboot unless you add the configuration to something like /etc/sysctl.conf).

Comment: I can't understand what all these comments about window scaling can possibly have to do with it. The bigger the receive window the better, surely? But the underlying problem is clearly that the receiver can't keep up with the sender. Solution: speed up the receiver, or slow down the sender.

Answer (score 1):

As well summarized [here](https://accedian.com/blog/tcp-receive-window-everything-need-know/):

> What Is a Zero Window?
>
> When a client (or server – but it is usually the client) advertises a zero value for its window size, this indicates that the TCP receive buffer is full and it cannot receive any more data. It may have a stuck processor or be busy with some other task, which can cause the TCP receive buffer to fill. Zero Windows can also be caused by a problem within the application, where the TCP buffer is not being retrieved.

My *guess* (as others have already stated, there's not enough data to perform a complete analysis) is that the *application* or lower level software isn't keeping up. No packet details are available but (again) I'm *guessing* they are **many** (thousands per second) and **small** (less than 500 bytes). A bandwidth such as "*62Mbps or 75Mbps*" can then become a problem due to the relative overhead added by TCP.

The bottleneck with *likely* be in the device's IP stack and/or the application handling of so many information pieces: a careful design is necessary to make sure that polling (if in use) or interrupts/events-driven approaches pull out as many data as possible in a single run.

Good luck and please provide additional requested details for more insightful answers.

Comment: I agree completely. The server cannot keep up with the send rate, so its receive buffer is filling, so the client's send buffer is filling, so the client can't send. Cure is to make the server faster or the client slower. I can't understand what all the comments about window scaling can possibly have to do with it.

Comment: "_I can't understand what all the comments about window scaling can possibly have to do with it._" @user207421

Window scaling is a TCP mechanism that can be used for that throttling: either "note that my remaining buffer is decreasing" (smaller window size adjustments) or "I can't take any more, please stop!" (zero window size). The latter seems to be (properly) triggered in the above screenshot. 